# Testing Conditional Data Binding in Angular

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have the following code:

```
<div class="myClass">
    {{ myFunction(a) ? person.name : "Name not given" }}
</div>
```

I want to be able to unit test this specific element in my HTML so that when the function `myFunction(a)` fails, I can ensure that the text is `Name not given`.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this using Jasmine?

Thanks

Comment: Well you can be pretty sure that ternary operations are going to work as expected, so I suggest you work on just testing the `myFunction` operation returns the appropriate results instead.

Comment: @Reddog I agree. `myFunction` is just a wrapper for checking if the element passed in is part of an array. I feel like testing the functionality of a built in JS method would be superfluous and I'm trying to brainstorm other possibilities for unit testing this line. Like you mentioned, the ternary statement won't fail and the index check probably won't as well. Any other suggestions?